# use Updator showing an error in resetpassword

Tags: php, laravel

In my laravel project i am using use Updater in my User model for the entry of created_by,updated_by and deleted_by.it works fine for all the action but showing an error for the resetpassword. Error

> ErrorException in Updater.php line 13: Trying to get property of
>   non-object

Updater.php

```
<?php 
namespace App; 
use Auth; 
trait Updater { protected static function boot() { 
        parent::boot(); /* * During a model create Eloquent will also update the updated_at field so * need to have the updated_by field here as well * */ 
        static::creating(function($model) { $model->created_by = Auth::user()->id;
                $model->updated_by = Auth::user()->id;
        });

        static::updating(function($model)  {

                $model->updated_by = Auth::user()->id;
        });
        /*
         * Deleting a model is slightly different than creating or deleting. For
         * deletes we need to save the model first with the deleted_by field
         * */
        static::deleting(function($model)  {

                $model->deleted_by = Auth::user()->id;
                $model->save();

        });
    }
}
```